# How to open a Modal from ContextMenu (Clicking Mouse Right)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to implement a context menu in my page. The script is working good, but Now I'd like open a modal when I do click some seccion from context menu.

I have the following HTML:

```
<!-- Body -->
<div id="contextMenu" class="content right-click">
</div>
```

and jQuery code:

```
    <!-- Context Menu (Right Click) -->
    <script src="../../plugins/contextMenu/js/contextmenu.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var $div = $('#contextMenu');

        // ContextMenu instance
        var cm = new ContextMenu({
            selector: '.right-click',
            callback: function(cmd, options) {
                switch (cmd) {
                    case 'SetLayer':
                        $div[0].style.backgroundColor = 'red';break;
                    case 'SetProjection':
                        $div[0].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';break;
                }
            },
            items: [
                {
                    text: 'Set Map',
                    items: [
                        {
                            text: 'Set Layer',
                            cmd: 'SetLayer',
                            target: '_blank',
                            url: ''
                        }, {
                            text: 'Set Projection',
                            cmd: 'SetProjection',
                            target: '_blank',
                            url: ''
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
</script>
```

I've tried to insert the following jQuery code into 'SetProjection':

```
$('#projectionModal').dialog('open');break;
```

But without-success.

By the way, when I do click on SetLayer or SetProjection I can change the BackGroundColor.

Comment: It's easier to help if you put your code in a jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really stupid... The only thing I had to change in the code:

```
$('#projectionModal').dialog('open');break;
```

to

```
$('#projectionModal').modal('show');
```